# DetailView template not displaying it's data

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

within an app I have two models, named Course and Step. Every Step belongs to a Course and each Course has many steps. However, I'm having problem creating a detailview for Steps. For example when i go to the url 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/courses/1' it should display steps for `course.objects.get(pk=1)`. However what i get back is just the page for course, i.e, http://127.0.0.1:8000/courses'.

Model

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Course(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 255)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Step(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    description = models.TextField()
    order = models.IntegerField()
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Url

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.course_list),
    url(r'(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.course_detail)
]
```

View

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.
from .models import Course, Step

def course_list(request):
    courses = Course.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'courses/course_list.html', {'courses': courses})

def course_detail(request, pk):
    course = Course.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'courses/course_detail.html', {'course': course})
```

course_detail.html

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% block title %}{{course.title}}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<article>
    <h2>{{ course.title }} %</h2>
    {{course.description}}
    <section>
        {% for step in course.step_set.all %}
        <h3>{{ step.title }}</h3>
        {{step.description}}
        {% endfor %}
    </section>
</article>
{% endblock %}
```

Main Urls

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from courses.views import course_list
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^courses/', course_list),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.hello_world),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

I just can't seem to recognize where i went wrong

Comment: I guess this `urls.py` is the one for your "courses" app. What is in your main `urls.py` file?

Comment: Just added my main urls.py file

Comment: There! The problem is that your main `urls.py` is not including the `urls.py` from the application, it is just resolving every path starting with `courses/` to the `course_list` view. I will add an answer.

Comment: Have you tried adding a / at the end of the URL in the browser? And add courses/ in your urls.py for the detail view before the pk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your main `urls.py` file - this line makes any URL path starting with 'courses/' resolve to the `course_list` view:

```
url(r'^courses/', course_list),
```

So Django will never reach the `course_detail` view. Instead, you must "include" the application-specific URLs:

```
url(r'^courses/', include('myproject.myapp.urls'),
```

Where `myproject` is your main project name, and `myapp` is your app name (make sure you also registered your application under `INSTALLED_APPS` at your `settings.py` file).

Comment: Brilliant. This seems to work. Thanks for all you're help

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, a good question is half the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the you need these url mappings..! This should do the trick.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^applicationName/$', views.ListView.as_view(), name='courses'),
    url(r'^applicationName/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.CourseDetailView.as_view(), name='course-detail'),
]
```